# Parametric representation of a plane cut of a sphere at y=5

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric

The sphere is given by $x^2+y^2+z^2=36$

Parametric Form:
$$x=6\sin t\cos u$$
$$y=6\sin t\sin u$$
$$z=6\cos t$$

If the sphere is 'cut' at $z=5$ this problem is trivial. ($0<t<\arccos(5/6),0<u<2\pi$), but although the sphere cut at $y=5$ seems to be just as simple, using the standard angle definitions of the parametric form of a sphere, we now have 2 unknowns instead of 1. How do I go about this?

Comment: I have edited your question to make use of this website's mathjax capabilities. Please review it to make sure I didn't introduce any errors.

Comment: Thanks Willie. That's correct.

Comment: Do you want a tangent plane at the surface of the sphere? A plane cuts a sphere into a circle. You want the equation for the circle when $y=5$? (BTW $y=5$ is a representation for a plane). A general plane has equation $Ax+By+Cz+D=0$.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is what values of $(t,u)$ belong to the plane $y=5$. Since that intersection of a sphere and a plane is a circle (2D curve) the result will be an implicit equation in terms of $t$ and $u$. In fact, you have

$$\sin(t) \sin(u) - \frac{5}{6}=0$$

The result is a closed curve wrapping around $(t=\frac{\pi}{2},u=\frac{\pi}{2})$. So your question is now *how do you parametrize this implicit curve* such that $t=t(s)$ and $u=u(s)$?

One way is to make $$ t(s)  = \arcsin\left(s \sqrt\frac{5}{6}\right) \\u(s)  = \arcsin\left(\frac{1}{s} \sqrt\frac{5}{6}\right)$$

for $s=\sqrt{\frac{5}{6}} \ldots \sqrt{\frac{6}{5}}$

In general, if the normal direction of the plane has a unit vector $(n_x,n_y,n_z)$ and a distance $d$ from the origin, then the implicit equation of the cut curve is

$$ n_z \cos(t)+n_x \sin(t)\cos(u)+n_y \sin(t)\sin(u) - \frac{d}{r} =0 $$

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a *new* angle in the plane of intersection as $v$.

$ t =\cos^{-1}(5/6),$ a fixed latitude t for all $ 0<u<2\pi. $

Cut radius $\rho=  \sqrt{6^2 -5^2} = \sqrt{ 11} $

$ (x = \rho \cos v, y = \rho \sin v, z = 5) $

Comment: Isn't this just a clever way of re-orienting the axes to make the sphere cut on the z-axis; which is a perfectly valid solution, however I need to make sure I don't re-orient the axes or introduce new angles (as a result of the context of the problem). I was thinking just setting t=pi/2 to solve for u and vice versa, but I'm not sure if this is correct. Thanks

Comment: @Tim To describe a space curve only one parameter is to be used, z to be kept constant...whichever way you do it.

Answer (score 0):

Choose for parametrization:
$$\begin{gathered}
  x = 6cos(t)cos(u) \hfill \\
  y = 6sin(t) \hfill \\
  z = 6cos(t)sin(u) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}$$
Rotate half circle around y-axis.
Then to solve
$$y = 6sin(t) = 5$$
is done as before. Choose right parametrization.